# HowTo: Create DIV using DOM without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

create dinamic and positional by user  
uses shall input params: offsetHeight, offsetLeft offsetParant, offsetTop, offsetWidth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a div with `document.createElement('div');`, but you can't set any of the properties you specified as they are all readonly.

You have to select appropriate CSS for the position you want and apply that instead.